# Python regular expression capture re-use

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a Python regular expression that will match a string if and only if that string begins and ends with the same lower-case letter.  The following seems like it ought to work, but matches every string:

`(?P<st>[a-z]).*(?P=st)$`

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^([a-z]).*\1$
```

This will require `back reference`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iV6mP5/5#python

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^([a-z]).*\1$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "a sdf sd fdsf sd a\nsdfdsf ASDSDSAD@#$@#ASDASDs\nsadasd Wdsda"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked for a regex, but then again, so many people ask that because they somehow think that's the only way to do these things.

```
>>> for s in ('test', 'foo', 'Test', ''):
    if s and s[0].islower() and s[0] == s[-1]:
        print('good:', s)

good: test
```